# Django: How to Like an Object with Ajax

Tags: python, django

Here's my View,

```
class ObjLike(RedirectView):
def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
    id = self.kwargs.get('id')
    obj = get_object_or_404(Data, id=id)
    user = self.request.user
    if user.is_authenticated():
        if user in obj.likes.all():
            obj.likes.remove(user)
        else:
            obj.likes.add(user)
```

So after this view how can I redirect user to the same page?

I used "return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])" but it gives an error "name 'request' is not defined"

I can't use the get absolute URL method, i'm using this view at several places.

So, how can I do that?

Comment: can you tell me what you are trying to do in this view because i think you should use ajax calls and not redirecting users then redirect them to previous page.

Comment: @mohammedqudah just allowing users to like Data :)

Comment: @mohammedqudah But don't know how to redirect to same page :(

Comment: then use ajax calles update your question to how to like an object with ajax so i can answer it

Comment: @mohammedqudah just updated sir :)

Comment: thank you please wait i am posting the answer : )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157231/discussion-between-mohammed-qudah-and-randomix).

Comment: join the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157231/discussion-between-mohammed-qudah-and-randomix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to like an object with ajax calls do this
first in html we want to make a like button:

```
<button id="like">Like!</button>
```

the add a script that contain the ajax:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#like").click(function(event){
        $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"{% url 'like' Obj.id %}",
             success: function(data){
                 confirm("liked")

             }
        });
        return false;
   });

});
</script>
```

the we add the like url to the urlpatterns list:

```
url(r'like/obj/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/', views.like, name="like"),
```

adding the view :

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def like(request, pk)
    obj = Obj.objects.get(id=pk)
    obj.likes += 1
    obj.save()
    return HttpResponse("liked")
```

> Note: you can customize the like view to check if user liked already

Comment: Wow, Thank You very much Sir :)