# How to make a button click update the database and redirect to a view in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, url

I have been struggling with this for a while, any help would be appreciated!

Basically, what I want to do is click an HTML button in Django, change a field in the database (of the object with the primary key in question), and redirect back to home.

**An example for clarity:**

Currently, I am working in the url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/edit/1/. The /1/ is the primary key of the model I want to change. The model is a custom group-model, with a field called "status". Status can be "approved", or "not approved":

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=Status.not_sent, choices=Status.choices(), null=False)
```

In the url result/edit/1/ I have an "Approve" button. When I click the button I want to change status in the model, and save that in the database. Also, after changing status I would like to redirect back to home. I have written the following method in views to do it:

```
def approve_group(request, pk):
    group = Group.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    group.status = Status.approved
    group.save()

    return redirect(request, 'home')
```

In the html, I have created the following button:

```
<a href="{% url 'resultregistration:approve_group' %}" />
    <button id="approve-btn" />Approve</button>
</a>
```

My reasoning is that the button should call this URL, which should again call the function in the view:

```
url(r'^result/approve/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.approve_group, name 
='approve_group'),
```

Unfortunately, this just gives a NoReverseMatch-error, and I am not sure how to proceed.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875587/django-how-to-like-an-object-with-ajax/46876021#46876021) because you need to use ajax calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view seems to have a mistake. It must not be a filter since it returns a queryset, it must be a get query since it returns the object in question:

```
def approve_group(request, pk):
    group = Group.objects.get(pk=pk)
    group.status = Status.approved
    group.save()
    return redirect(request, 'home')
```

And I think it will be better to use POST request for making changes in Jquery. Maybe something like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'resultregistration:approve_group' pk=my_pk %}" method=POST>
<button id="approve-btn" type="submit">Approve</button>
</form>
```

By doing so a POST request is sent to the view, and in return can be redirected to homepage. And please make sure whether the namespace(resultregistration) is given correctly or not.

Answer (score 4):

What's missing here is the pk for the url. So you need to fill in that too to be able to generate a reverse. You can read more about it in the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

```
<a href="{% url 'resultregistration:approve_group' pk=my_pk %}" />
    <button id="approve-btn" />Approve</button>
</a>
```

Comment: Although the above answer is correct, I would advise against using a GET request to make changes to the database. Good for beginners, but in the long run, you want to add a form to your HTML file and POST the approve status. And your view should only make the change if it's a POST request.

Comment: Wise words by dirkgroten.

Comment: No no no, he should use ajax calls no need to redirect the user

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, I still get the same error: 
"Reverse for 'approve_group' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. "

I tried writing pk=Group.pk, but that is probably wrong!

Comment: which view is rendering the HTML with the button? That view must pass the `pk` into the template rendering as context variable.